# Optaplanner Mista 2013 Output files

Tags: scheduling, optaplanner

I was reading through the MISTA 2013 challenge document. The suggested output format was--

*For each activity j of project i,
 the selected mode mij ,
 and the start time sij ,*

Right now the output of optaplanner is an XML file. Is there any code developed to convert it into the output format as required by MISTA. Can anyone please share the same

Thanks

Comment: As we submitted solutions in the competition's format, there should be an ...Exporter class in that example.

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded the files available on Optaplanner.org but I am able to find only XML. The tool output is also in XML onlyCan you please guide me better?

Comment: Have you tried the export button? But this is an example, not an end-user tool.

Comment: Hi, the export button is greyed out. I understand it is not an end user tool. I am trying to show usability of the optaplanner to solve some of my line problems. I am trying draw out the output from XML but if it is already available then it would be really useful

Comment: You're right, it's grayed out: there is no ProjectJobSchedulingExporter class even, so it seems we never wrote it and submitted any result to the challenge...